# Except can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. array<string> <> string at the second column of the second table

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my code for except

```
A.except(B)
```

The original schema for A and B looks like this

String Column A     List of Strings Column B     String Column C

and before except I do

```
.withColumn("Column B", explode(col("Column B")))
```

This is the exact error message I am getting

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
 Except can only be performed on tables with the compatible column 
 types. array<string> <> string at the second column of the second 
 table;;
'Except
:- Project [Column A#14, Column B#170, Column C#112]
:  +- Generate explode(Column B#126), true, false, [Column B#170]
:     +- Project [Column A#14, Column B#126, Column C#112]
:        +- Aggregate [Column A#14, Column C#112], 
[Column A#14, Column C#112, collect_list(Column B#15, 0, 0) AS 
 Column B#126]
:           +- Project [Column A#14, Column B#15, zeroString#16, 
Column C#9, substring_index(Column C#33, :0, 1) AS Column C#112]
:              +- Deduplicate [Column C#9, Column C#33, 
zeroString#16, Column B#15, Column A#14], false
:                 +- Project [Column A#14, Column B#15, zeroString#16, 
Column C#9, Column C#33]
:                    +- Generate explode(if ((isnull(0) || isnull(10))) 
null else UDF(Column C#9, 0, 10)), true, false, [Column C#33]
:                       +- Filter (UDF(Column C#9) >= 100)
:                          +- Filter Column A#14 IN (1)
:                             +- Project [rawKey#5[0] AS 
Column A#14, rawKey#5[1] AS Column B#15, rawKey#5[2] AS 
zeroString#16, Column C#9]
:                                +- Project [rawKey#5, 
rawValue#1, split(rawValue#1, \|) AS Column C#9]
:                                   +- Project 
[split(rawKey#0, \|) AS rawKey#5, 
rawValue#1]
:                                      +- 
Relation[rawKey#0,rawValue#1] csv
+- LogicalRDD [Column A#162, Column B#163, Column C#164]
```

Comment: isn't the error message clear enough to understand? the error message has more than enough information for you to debug

Comment: Yes, my concern was why was the second column being considered as list of string when I was clearly doing an explode. But on closer look I had initialized one of the DFs with List of string as schema before these lines which was causing the issue.